Playwright, Adyen, Safari Mobile, element is not editable
I am using Playwright to test a card payment feature implemented with Adyen dropin (iframe).
Tests work fine in all browser emulations except for "Safari Mobile".
The cardnumber input field looks like this when inspecting:
<input id="adyen-checkout-encryptedCardNumber-1712080102156" data-fieldtype="encryptedCardNumber" type="text" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="24" autocomplete="cc-number" placeholder="1234 5678 9012 3456" aria-label="Kortnummer" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="adyen-checkout-encryptedCardNumber-1712080102156-ariaContext" class="js-iframe-input input-field" data-type="gsf" style="display: block;">

I can get a hold of the input field in the test.
const cardNumberInputField = cardNumberFrame.getByPlaceholder("1234 5678 9012 3456");
await expect(cardNumberInputField).toBeVisible();
await cardNumberInputField.fill("4111 1111 1111 1111");

, but when I try to fill it with test data the field does not seem to be editable.
locator resolved to <input type="text" maxlength="24" data-type="gsf" reado…/>
elementHandle.fill("4111 1111 1111 1111")
waiting for element to be visible, enabled and editable
element is not editable - waiting...

UPDATE:
I could make the tests pass by removing the readonly attribute like this:
async function removeReadOnlySafariMobile(elementHandle) {
  await elementHandle.evaluate((node) => node.removeAttribute("readonly"));
}

But I'd rather learn why this is happening in the Safari Mobile emulation?
Thanks!

Please share the page or a [mcve] of it along with your full code. I see what looks like a readonly property peeking out there, so you may need to interact further with the UI to edit this.

calling click() method on input element then fill("") works for me. I am using the Adyen Credit Card Web Component and faced the same issue.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
